# c# ZedGraph: Динамическое прокручивание графика

Tags: c#, zedgraph

График постоянно получает данные. Их может быть очень много. Поэтому очень неудобно, когда при поступлении новых данных на график, он сжимается.

Как можно автоматически прокручивать график, вслед за новым данными?

---

Суть примера состоит в том, что к данным периодически (с интервалом 100 мс) добавляются новые числа, при этом надо выводить только последние 30 значений.
[Источник](https://jenyay.net/ZedGraph/Queue)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Максимальный размер очереди
    /// </summary>
    int _capacity = 30;

    /// <summary>
    /// Здесь храним данные
    /// </summary>
    List<double> _data;

    /// <summary>
    /// Для генерации слуайных данные по таймеру
    /// </summary>
    Random _rnd = new Random ();

    // Интервал изменения данных по вертикали
    double _ymin = -1.0;
    double _ymax = 1.0;

    System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
    public Form1 ()
    {
        _data = new List<double> ();

        InitializeComponent ();
        timer.Interval = 1000; //интервал между срабатываниями 1000 миллисекунд
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick); //подписываемся на события Tick
        timer.Start();
        DrawGraph ();
    }

    private void timer_Tick (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Вычислим новое значение
        double newValue = _rnd.NextDouble () * (_ymax - _ymin) + _ymin;

        // Добавим его в конец списка
        _data.Add (newValue);

        // Удалим первый элемент в списке данных, 
        // если заполнили максимальную емкость
        if (_data.Count > _capacity)
        {
            _data.RemoveAt (0);
        }

        DrawGraph ();
    }

    private void DrawGraph ()
    {
        // Получим панель для рисования
        GraphPane pane = zedGraph.GraphPane;

        // Очистим список кривых на тот случай, если до этого сигналы уже были нарисованы
        pane.CurveList.Clear ();

        // Создадим список точек
        PointPairList list = new PointPairList ();

        // Интервал, где есть данные
        double xmin = 0;
        double xmax = _capacity;

        // Расстояние между соседними точками по горизонтали
        double dx = 1.0;

        double curr_x = 0;

        // Заполняем список точек
        foreach (double val in _data)
        {
            list.Add (curr_x, val);
            curr_x += dx;
        }

        // Очистим список кривых от прошлых рисунков (кадров)
        pane.CurveList.Clear ();
        LineItem myCurve = pane.AddCurve ("Random Value", list, Color.Blue, SymbolType.None);


        // Устанавливаем интересующий нас интервал по оси X
        pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = xmin;
        pane.XAxis.Scale.Max = xmax;

        // Устанавливаем интересующий нас интервал по оси Y
        pane.YAxis.Scale.Min = _ymin;
        pane.YAxis.Scale.Max = _ymax;

        // Вызываем метод AxisChange (), чтобы обновить данные об осях. 
        // В противном случае на рисунке будет показана только часть графика, 
        // которая умещается в интервалы по осям, установленные по умолчанию
        zedGraph.AxisChange ();

        // Обновляем график
        zedGraph.Invalidate ();
    }
}
```

Comment: не в курсе работы с вашим контролом, но вы пробовали удалять старые данные при добавлении новых?

Comment: нашел решение, пример кода https://jenyay.net/ZedGraph/Queue

Comment: у меня не откроется эта ссылка.. Будет лучше, если вы добавите ответ на свой вопрос

Comment: Я в своё время сделал словарь (ось Х - дата, ось Y - значение) размер которого задал в конфиге, чтобы можно было управлять в будущем количеством точек. При инициализации словаря добавлял нулевые значения (чтобы постоянно иметь заданный масштаб). После добавления нового элемента удалял первый, если количество элементов превышает заданное. А уж после отрисовывал график. Получается очень красиво. График отрисовывается как кардиограмма со сдвигом справа налево. [Пример](https://i0.wp.com/rootware.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Infrared_Station_Review.jpg) работы.